# Maximum stack depth exceeded Laravel Collection Resource

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-collection

Here is code:

```
class Profile extends JsonResource
{

public function toArray($request)
{

    return [
        'data' => [
            'type' => 'profiles',
            'profile_id' => $this->id,
            'attributes' => [
                'avatar' => $this->avatar,
                'gender' => $this->gender,
                'observers' => new ProfileCollection(\App\Profile::whereIn('user_id', $this->observers->pluck('id'))->get()),
                'observing' => new ProfileCollection($this->user->observing),
                'birthday' => optional($this->birthday)->format('m/d/Y'),
                'address' => $this->address,
                'friendship' => new FriendResource(Friend::friendship($this->user->id)),
            ]
        ],
        'links' => [
            'self' => url('/profiles/' . $this->id)
        ]
    ];
}
}
```

The problem in observers and observing. When I use both this properties I get error:
Maximum stack depth exceeded

WHen i turn off one of them, so all work excellent. This Profile class is - resource, so I call in observers and observing collections of this resource.

I can't understand how to increase depth of json in this case?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the User Model?

Comment: public function observing()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class, 'observers', 'user_id', 'profile_id')
            ->withTimestamps();

    }

Comment: I think its because of recursive calling profile resource again and again. I will change this and call it from another resource)

Comment: Just don't call any resource in the ProfileResource, why not iterate over the `$this->observers`, create an array according to the requirement and then add it here in the returning array.

Comment: I solved it by creating another resource of model which is hierarhy parent of profile - its UserResource. So in it I can include Profile. The problem is because I have unlimited iteration of calling ProfileCollection inside another ProfileCollection. Thus I have bad Resource construction

Answer (score 0):

They must be a loop in the way you are retrieving data may be in user observing there is a user profile which will again look for a use observing which will look for user profile and so on